# How do I make BigInteger see the binary representation of this Hex string correctly?

Tags: c#, biginteger, performance, twos-complement

**The problem**

I have a `byte[]` that is converted to a hex string, and then that string is parsed like this `BigInteger.Parse(thatString,NumberSyles.Hexnumber)`.

This seems wasteful since BigInteger is able to accept a byte[], as long as the two's complement is accounted for.

---

**An working (inefficient) example**

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) the most significant bit of the last byte should be zero in order for the following hex number be a positive one.  The following is an example of a hex number that has this issue:

```
byte[] ripeHashNetwork = GetByteHash();
foreach (var item in ripeHashNetwork)
{
   Console.Write(item + "," );
} 

// Output:  
//      0,1,9,102,119,96,6,149,61,85,103,67,158,94,57,248,106,13,39,59,238,214,25,103,246

// Convert to Hex string using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/328397
// Output: 
//       00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6`
```

Okay, let's pass that string into the static method of `BigInteger`:

```
 BigInteger bi2 = BigInt.Parse(thatString,NumberSyles.Hexnumber);

// Output bi2.ToString() ==
//                {25420294593250030202636073700053352635053786165627414518}
```

Now that I have a baseline of data, and known conversions that work, I want to make it better/faster/etc.

---

**A not working (efficient) example**

Now my goal is to round-trip a `byte[]` into `BigInt` and make the result look like  `25420294593250030202636073700053352635053786165627414518`. Let's get started:

So according to MSDN I need a zero in my last byte to avoid my number from being seen as a two's compliment.  I'll add the zero and print it out to be sure:

```
foreach (var item in ripeHashNetwork)
{
   Console.Write(item + "," );
} 

// Output:                            
//    0,1,9,102,119,96,6,149,61,85,103,67,158,94,57,248,106,13,39,59,238,214,25,103,246,0
```

Okay, let's pass that `byte[]` into the constructor of `BigInteger`:

```
 BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(ripeHashNetwork);

// Output bi2.ToString() ==
//                {1546695054495833846267861247985902403343958296074401935327488}
```

What I skipped over is the sample of what bigInt does to my byte array if I don't add the trailing zero.  What happens is that I get a negative number which is wrong.  I'll post that if you want.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the part about "little endian order" ?  I think your baseline is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are going via the hex string, the first byte of your array is becoming the most significant byte of the resulting BigInteger.

When you are adding a trailing zero, the last bye of your array is the most significant.

I'm not sure which case is *right* for you, but that's why you're getting different answers.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN "The individual bytes in the value array should be in little-endian order, from lowest-order byte to highest-order byte". So the mistake is the order of bytes:

```
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(ripeHashNetwork.Reverse().ToArray<byte>());
```

Comment: Note that he'll need to add the trailing zero after calling Reverse, not before.

Comment: yes, my fault. Tested it with byte[] ripeHashNetwork = new byte[] { 0, 1, 9, 102, 119, 96, 6, 149, 61, 85, 103, 67, 158, 94, 57, 248, 106, 13, 39, 59, 238, 214, 25, 103, 246, 0 };